# Extracting knn regression model

Tags: r, regression, knn

I found the package about "k Nearest Neighbor Regression" for R.  I tried the example (see below), but what I want to do is to save the created Regression Model (pac.knn). How can I do save or extract the model and apply it outside of R?

```
if(require(chemometrics)){
data(PAC);
pac.knn<- knn.reg(PAC$X, y=PAC$y, k=3);
pac.knn.VR<- knn.reg(PAC$X, y=PAC$y, k=3, algorith="VR");

plot(PAC$y, pac.knn$pred, xlab="y", ylab=expression(hat(y)))
points(PAC$y, pac.knn.VR$pred, col=2, pch=3);}
```

Comment: You can save R objects to a file using `?save`. But you'll need to be much more specific about what you mean by "applying the model outside of R". There isn't really a model to extract with knn; the training data _is_ the model.

Comment: Hello joran, thanks a lot! Now I understood how nearest neighbour method works. It looks only to the nearest dataset of the independent variables and evaluates for example through building an euclidean distance and so on... and calculate the target value by considering the similarity! For every iteration/calculation the complete dataset have to been analyzed!

Comment: I too think it would be very useful if the KD Tree (or Cover Tree or whichever method was chosen) could be extracted and stored for later use.  In my case I wouldn't need it outside R, just later within R.